# not able to get parameters from jsp to spring controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am not able to get the values from JSP to my Spring controller, below is the my code snippet.

in JSP I have defined parameters like

```
<input type="hidden" id="categoryId" name="categoryId" value="<c:out value="${category.categoryId}"/>" />
<input type="hidden" id="sortBy" name="sortBy" value="<c:out value="${requestScope.sortBy}"/>" />
<input type="hidden" id="orderBy" name="orderBy" value="<c:out value="${requestScope.orderBy}"/>" />
```

And my controller is looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "category/listCategory.htm")
public ModelAndView getList(HttpServletRequest request) {

     long longCurrentPage = CommonUtils.checkPaginationAttributes(request);
     String orderBy = request.getParameter(const_OrderBy);
     String sortBy = request.getParameter(const_SortBy);    
     List<Category> categoryList = categoryService.getCategoryList(longCurrentPage, orderBy, sortBy);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    request.setAttribute("currentPage", new Long(longCurrentPage));
        request.setAttribute(const_OrderBy, orderBy);
        request.setAttribute(const_SortBy, sortBy); 
    ModelAndView modelandView = new ModelAndView("listCategory","categoryList",categoryList);
```

From controller to JSP values are setting fine, while getting the same values from JSP is getting null's

I also tried with

```
public ModelAndView getList(
        @RequestParam(value = "orderBy", required = false, defaultValue = "") String orderBy,
        @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false, defaultValue = "") String sortBy,
        @RequestParam(value = "oortBy", required = false, defaultValue = "") String oortBy,
        @RequestParam(value = "isPaginationClicked", required = false, defaultValue = "") String isPaginationClicked,
        @RequestParam(value = "currentPage", required = false, defaultValue = "") String currentPage)
```

Still Im not getting values,

Pls help.. thanks in Advance...

Comment: you need to post whole jsp page in order to see where is your problem. This arise many questions, maybe you don't have form tag enclosing input's.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Spring input tag instead of HTML input tag.

First define the namespace:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

Then use Spring input tag:

```
<form:input type="hidden" id="categoryId" path="categoryId" value="<c:outvalue="${category.categoryId}"/>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can use spring tab like `<sf:input .../>` to define your input field
(`<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>`), and embrace all the field in the JSP that you want to post the server side. That should work.

Second, in the controller, you can defind a object like ListDTO, which contain all the field you post from the JSP page and add `@ModelAttribute` to the argument of method, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "category/listCategory.htm")
public ModelAndView getList(HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute ListDTO listDTO) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, It's worked for me after I took spring form tags and a seperate DTO object to transfer the data from JSP, But still I dont understand why I am not able to access input fields from request object in my controller.
anyway my problem is solved, thanks to you both.